# Navigation bar error on IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard, uistoryboard

I am developing an app on Xcode 5 with this structure

[image: app schema]

All was great until I have added the last view, which is a simple view that gives more information about the object you have selected in the previous `UICollectionView`.

When I click on the `Cell` the next view appears, but corrupted and I also get the following error

```
[6313:a0b] nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar
[6313:a0b] Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. 
           Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.
```

And then when I click on "Back" the following error appears and the app crashes:

```
[6313:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',
           reason: 'Can't add self as subview'
```

All the connections are simple pushes

Any clue?

Thanks in advance

Edit:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:
(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if (collectionView == _collectionView2){
         selectedOffer = [offerArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"offerDetail" sender:collectionView];
    }

 }
 -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"offerDetail"]){
        OfferDetailViewController *con = (OfferDetailViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
        con.myOffer = selectedOffer;
    }   
}
```

Comment: show us the code in collectionView:DidselectItemAtIndexPath: . we want to know the way you present the last view

Comment: if u do with some another method

Comment: This error  usually course when you have 2 animations going on at the same time. From the structure i can't tell what is going on. What animations do you use in there ?

Comment: create the barbutton and give the seque to the next controller using Push, and then given the identifier name of the push,finally call the identifier name to the collectionView:DidselectItemAtIndexPath just like [self performsequeidentifier:@"identifier name" sender:self];

Comment: it surely works for u

Comment: @santhu I have edited the question adding the methos as you said.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Your solution was perfect. Thank you very much! So the key was the sender, no? The sender must be a view to continue navigating properly. Did I get it?  Should I answer my question in the question itself, answer myself, or leave it? Noob over here :)